# Infer the joint distribution of random vector from the sum of its co-ordinates

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $a, b, c \in \mathrm R$ be such, that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.
Let $U=(X,Y,Z)$ be a random vector, about what we know is only that $aX+bY+cZ$ is uniformly distributed on $(-1, 1)$ line (for each a,b,c satisfying the condition $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$).
Show $U$ is uniformly distributed on unit sphere $S_3$.

I totally have no idea where to start.
Everything i can conclude by myself is for that $U$ distribution, if there exists positive mass outside of $S_3$, then $aX+bY+cZ$ whould not be uniformly distributed on $(-1,1)$

Comment: For each of them

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity, i have edited the post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  You could start by verifying that the uniform distribution on $S_3$ has the desired property.

Comment: Okay, I've got this. Let $p=(a,b,c), ||p||=1$ and $u=(x,y,z)$. Let''s assume $u$ comes from uniform distribution on $S_3$, which implies $||u||=1$ for sure. Let $\alpha=\measuredangle (p, v)$. Then $p \cdot u = \cos(\alpha)$.
$\mathrm F(t)=\mathrm P(aX+bY+cZ<t)=\mathrm P(\cos(\alpha)<t)$. With the last equality it's straightforward to compute that probability as the measure of the surface of the sphere slice, which leds to $F(t)=\mathbb{1}_{(-1, 1)}(t) \cdot \frac{1-t}{2} $

Comment: Good.  Is there some other distribution on $\mathbb R^3$ with the same 1-dimensional margins?  If not, you are done.

Comment: Uniform distribution on $(-1,1)\mathrm x(-1,1)\mathrm x(-1,1)$ has the same margins as that one on $S_3$. Also: I made a mistake above and $F(t)$ should be equal to $\frac{t+1}{2}$

Comment: The issue is, can there be a _different_ distribution with the same margins?

Comment: By marginal distribution you mean distribution $\mu_{X_i}(A)=\mu(R_1,...,R_{i-1}, A,R_{i+1},..R_n)$ for a random vector $(X_1, ... X_n)$ with values in $R_1xR_2...xR_n$ and so on?

Comment: In that sense, are'nt uniform distributions on cube, and on sphere different?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that the distribution of a $\mathbb R^n$-valued random  vector is completely specified by  the distributions of all the linear forms in $X$, that is, by the distributions of $\langle \alpha, X\rangle$ for all $\alpha\in \mathbb (R^n)^*$.  (To know the distribution of $\langle \alpha, X\rangle$ is to know the 1-dimensional characteristic function $\phi_\alpha(t)=E\exp(it\langle \alpha, X\rangle)$.  To know all the $\phi_\alpha$ functions is  enough to determine the multivariate characteristic function $\phi(\tau)=E\exp(i\langle\tau,X\rangle)$, using the formula $\phi(t\alpha)=\phi_\alpha(t)$.) This is the [Cramér–Wold theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem) ; it is the basic reason why CAT scans work.

In the present problem, a simple calculation shows that the uniform distribution on the surface of the unit sphere is such that for every $\alpha$, the marginal distribution of $\langle\alpha,X\rangle$ is $U[-\|\alpha\|,\|\alpha\|]$.
These marginals are what you get by integrating the multivariate distribution of $X$ on hyperplanes orthogonal to $\alpha$.
The C-W result shows this is the only distribution with this property.